# web based softphone in Asterisk

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sip, asterisk, mjsip

We want to build the web-based softphone using SIP technology 
And we want to use the Asterisk as the Communication server and Java as primary technology in building the system

so we have got following

- flash based softphone using Adobe Flash,FMG,FMS
- flex based softphone using Flex , Red5 Server

we are also reseraching into [MjSIP](http://www.mjsip.org/) and [PjSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/)

My questions are following -

1. for building this kind of softphone , can we use the Java Applets ?
2. The flash will be better option for the system   ?

Please give any suggetions for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had good experience with Red5Phone. The SIP UA is running in a servlet container, flash is only needed for recording/playing out sound to/from RTMP.

There was some inconvenience involved at the time in using the Java Media Framework from a java applet.

Comment: is there any requirement for the Media server like the Red5, Flash Media server ?

Comment: Yes, the SIP user agent is running on the red5 server, relaying media to/from the simple flash client running in the browser connecting to speakers and microphone.  A truly in-browser softphone without a server component registering to any standard SIP registrar and accepting calls from anywhere will require listening on port 5060 to begin with. I don't think either flash or HTML5 can do that, maybe AIR can?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a browser based softphone you are writing you can rule out pjsip, it's written in C so  no option to run in a browser there.

Flash and Java are options and in the past I've seen softphone implementations with both so it is possible. However for whatever reason they were never really up to scratch and didn't get any popular support. I suspect once you get down to the media side of things needing to process large numbers of UDP packets in real-time the constraints of having to operate within a browser may start to bite.

The latest effort I'm aware of is [phono](http://phono.com/) from voxeo which is a flash/javascript hybrid softphone. It has a javascript API that hooks back into voxeo's SIP servers which then do the call signalling and set the media up between the flash plugin in the browser and the remote end of the call. It seems to work pretty well or as well as you can expect from a real-time product in a browser.

If I was you I'd start looking at [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) once it's supported in browsers it will be a much better option as you'll then be able to access network sockets directly from javascript and processing of media in real-time within a browser should be much more practical.

Comment: Softphone using JavaScript + WebRTC:  
See: https://github.com/ricardojlrufino/webphone-sip